# Email address on Django API returns 404

Tags: python, django, api, backend

I have an endpoint created like this:

```
class OTPSViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for listing or retrieving users.
    """
    throttle_classes = [OncePerDayUserThrottle]
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        response = self.get_otp(pk)
        return response

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = OtpsForms(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            response = self.verify_otp(request)
            return response
        else:
            return response_error(serializer.errors)

    def get_otp(self, username):
        """Send OTP by email

        Args:
            username (string): username
        """
        username = username.strip().lower()
        user = _get_all_by_username(username)
        ...
```

What happens is that when I make a call to the endpoint with a "username" such as "javi" or "javi@gmail", the call "GET /api/otps/javi/ HTTP/1.1" 200" returns a 200, and when the username is an email like "javi@gmail.com" the call is "GET /api/otps/javi@gmail.com/ HTTP/1.1" 404" returning a 404 not found status.

I think it has to do with having dot (.) inside the url but I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should encode `@` symbol and the `.`, remember to decode it on the server.

Comment: Can you show the router/url for that view

Comment: @rahul.m I have it like this: ```router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r"otps", OTPSViewSet, "otps") ```

Comment: Django tells you that it can not find the user javi@gmail.com. You didn't provide enough info to tell you more than this.

Comment: @alv2017 the thing is that the user javi@gmail.com exists as user "javi" does. They are the same kind of users only with different usernames

Comment: @alv2017 i found that it is related with the dot (.) and not with the @, I have been doing tests with postman, and with "javi" it works and with "javi." it returns Not found 404

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is related to the URL encoding. Instead of `/api/otps/javi@gmail.com/` try using the URL below:

```
/api/otps/javi%40gmail.com/
```

Comment: It is related with the dot (.) inside the email, a request with "javi" gives output but with "javi." it returns a 404

Comment: Oh @javier-crespo, aren't we facing a SQL threat injection here? :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it adding `lookup_value_regex = '[^/]+'` at the beginning of the viewset and now it is working